# Ruby Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dylib, canvas-lms

I'm running the command `bundle exec rails canvas:compile_assets` to [install Canvas LMS on localhost](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start). However, I get the following error

> LoadError: dlopen(/Users/parzival/.rbenv/versions/2.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure-0.9.7/lib/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib

Traceback:

```
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/parzival/.rbenv/versions/2.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure-0.9.7/lib/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/parzival/.rbenv/versions/2.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure-0.9.7/lib/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/parzival/.rbenv/versions/2.6.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure-0.9.7/lib/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle

/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/config/application.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/Rakefile:6:in `require'
/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/bin/rails:16:in `require'
/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/bin/rails:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/bin/spring:20:in `require'
/Users/parzival/exempt/canvas/bin/spring:20:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:5:in `load'
bin/rails:5:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to search for similar questions on StackOverflow but only found answers for Python/Conda Environment.

I'm using MacOS Big Sur 11.1 and Ruby 2.6.7. Node version 14.16.1 and npm version 6.14.12.

**What I've Tried** (Edit on April 29, 2021)

- Reinstalling Node, PHP using Homebrew, and all other solutions specified in this [GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded)
- Reinstalled yarn, npm, gem, bundle, rails, and all dependencies
- Installing different versions of Node, (my system default is v16, I installed v14 for this project, also tried with v12)
- Reinstalled the package from instructure and repeated installation process
- Reinstalled `nokogiri-xmlsec-instructure`(which seems to be causing the error); tried different versions but none appeared to be compatible with other dependencies
- run `brew upgrade` and many other commands to upgrade to the latest version

However, none of the above options I tried worked. The same error still persists.

As @Siguza mentioned requested in the comments, nothing returns when I run `find /Users/parzival/.rbenv -name libicui18n.58.dylib`. I also searched for this file on my device, but it's nowhere to be found.

Please let me know if you need any additional info - I'd be happy to provide them. Any help to fix this issue is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: try "npm version" and see if you see the same error. If so, try to upgrade your node version "brew upgrade npm" and then check again.

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for the response! `npm version` shows no errors. I tried upgrading npm but the error still persists

Comment: then reinstalling can help. see https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded

Comment: @Vishal tried all solutions presented in the post... but unfortunately, none worked for me

Comment: Can you post the output of `find /Users/parzival/.rbenv -name libicui18n.58.dylib`?

Comment: @Siguza Running directly gives me permission denied, but if I run with `sudo`, nothing is returned